# FreeBSD pfsense root CA fails

Tags: freebsd, pfsense, certificate-authority

I have some problem with root CA of my pfsense installation.
My test script is this:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net:443
```

And the answer is:

```
 Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

I tried to update CA roots with

```
pkg install security/ca_root_nss
```

but nothing changes... what can it be?

Answer (score 0):

ca_root_nss is included by default. openssl probably just needs to be pointed to the cert.pem file if you're calling it directly like that. Using fetch instead, 'fetch https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net', will verify whether the cert is recognized by the OS in general.